# Creating a queue of linklabels/Buttons dynamically in C++ win Forms

Tags: c++

I want to Create a queue of linklabels/Buttons Dynamically in Winform, C++. When I click a button a linklabel appears dynamically as link1. If I click the button second time link1 should drop below and link2 should appear on top of link1. On clicking the button third time link1 should drop down, link2 should take link1 position and link3 should take link2 position and so on. You can see it like a queue. The queue should have five items and on clicking the button sixth time, link 1 should disappear and link 6 should be on top. This continues on and on.

I have accomplished some of the tasks. I have create linklabels dynamically. I thought of deleting all the linklabels each time a button is clicked and recreate them by reordering their positions based on the number of clicks. But couldn't delete the linklabels. I even tried to overwrite a new linklabel on top of another linklabel, but the previous linklabel doesnt go off and shows some exception error if I click the overwritten linklabel.

Comment: Can we see your minimal ,complete code?

Comment: @psyco, the function below creates linklabels serially from top to bottom based on no of clicks. And if no of clicks =6 the link 6 overwrites on top of link1. If no of clicks=7 link 7 overwrites on top of link 2 and son on.

Answer (score 0):

```
`void History_Links()
{
                string name=record[0];
                LinkLabel^ lbl=gcnew LinkLabel();
                lbl->Parent=this;
                lbl->Location=System::Drawing::Point(10,300+(no_of_clicks-1)*15);
                lbl->Size=System::Drawing::Size(55,15);
                lbl->Name=gcnew String(link_names[no_of_clicks-1].c_str());
                lbl->Text= gcnew String(name.c_str());
                lbl->AutoSize = true;


                switch(no_of_clicks)
                 {
                   case 1 :
                      lbl->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::history1_LinkClicked); 
                      break;
                   case 2 :
                       //lbl->Clear();
                      lbl->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::history2_LinkClicked); 
                      break;
                   case 3 :
                      lbl->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::history3_LinkClicked); 
                      break;
                   case 4 :
                      lbl->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::history4_LinkClicked); 
                      break;
                   case 5 :
                      lbl->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::history5_LinkClicked); 
                      break;
                  }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vcclr.h>
//#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
//#include <chrono>
//using namespace msclr::interop;

namespace HistoryTracker {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;

    string history[1000],record[50];
    //string link_names[5]={"history1","history2","history3","history4","history5"};
    int no_of_clicks=0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: AxAcroPDFLib::AxAcroPDF^  axAcroPDF1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel^  linkLabel1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel^  linkLabel2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel^  linkLabel3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel^  linkLabel4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel^  linkLabel5;



    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->axAcroPDF1 = (gcnew AxAcroPDFLib::AxAcroPDF());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->linkLabel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel());
            this->linkLabel2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel());
            this->linkLabel3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel());
            this->linkLabel4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel());
            this->linkLabel5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->axAcroPDF1))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(909, 11);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(122, 37);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"Choose Files";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // axAcroPDF1
            // 
            this->axAcroPDF1->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom) 
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Left) 
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->axAcroPDF1->Enabled = true;
            this->axAcroPDF1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(623, 55);
            this->axAcroPDF1->Name = L"axAcroPDF1";
            this->axAcroPDF1->OcxState = (cli::safe_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AxHost::State^  >(resources->GetObject(L"axAcroPDF1.OcxState")));
            this->axAcroPDF1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(515, 580);
            this->axAcroPDF1->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(16, 11);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label1->Text = L"label1";
            this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::label1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1037, 11);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 37);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 3;
            this->button2->Text = L"Exit";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
            // 
            // linkLabel1
            // 
            this->linkLabel1->AutoSize = true;
            this->linkLabel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(15, 300);
            this->linkLabel1->Name = L"linkLabel1";
            this->linkLabel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(13, 13);
            this->linkLabel1->TabIndex = 4;
            this->linkLabel1->TabStop = true;
            this->linkLabel1->Text = L"";
            this->linkLabel1->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::linkLabel1_LinkClicked);
            // 
            // linkLabel2
            // 
            this->linkLabel2->AutoSize = true;
            this->linkLabel2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(15, 315);
            this->linkLabel2->Name = L"linkLabel2";
            this->linkLabel2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(13, 13);
            this->linkLabel2->TabIndex = 5;
            this->linkLabel2->TabStop = true;
            this->linkLabel2->Text = L"";
            this->linkLabel2->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::linkLabel2_LinkClicked);
            // 
            // linkLabel3
            // 
            this->linkLabel3->AutoSize = true;
            this->linkLabel3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(15, 330);
            this->linkLabel3->Name = L"linkLabel3";
            this->linkLabel3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(13, 13);
            this->linkLabel3->TabIndex = 6;
            this->linkLabel3->TabStop = true;
            this->linkLabel3->Text = L"";
            this->linkLabel3->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::linkLabel3_LinkClicked);
            // 
            // linkLabel4
            // 
            this->linkLabel4->AutoSize = true;
            this->linkLabel4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(15, 345);
            this->linkLabel4->Name = L"linkLabel4";
            this->linkLabel4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(13, 13);
            this->linkLabel4->TabIndex = 7;
            this->linkLabel4->TabStop = true;
            this->linkLabel4->Text = L"";
            this->linkLabel4->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::linkLabel4_LinkClicked);
            // 
            // linkLabel5
            // 
            this->linkLabel5->AutoSize = true;
            this->linkLabel5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(15, 360);
            this->linkLabel5->Name = L"linkLabel5";
            this->linkLabel5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(13, 13);
            this->linkLabel5->TabIndex = 8;
            this->linkLabel5->TabStop = true;
            this->linkLabel5->Text = L"";
            this->linkLabel5->LinkClicked += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this, &Form1::linkLabel5_LinkClicked);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1150, 647);
            this->Controls->Add(this->linkLabel5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->linkLabel4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->linkLabel3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->linkLabel2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->linkLabel1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->axAcroPDF1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->axAcroPDF1))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                OpenFileDialog^ opendialog =gcnew OpenFileDialog;
                opendialog-> ShowDialog(); 
                axAcroPDF1->src=opendialog->FileName;

                String^ file_name=opendialog->FileName;
                std::string stan_string ;
                //std::string stan_string = marshal_as<string>(file_name);
                MarshalString(opendialog->FileName->ToString(),stan_string);
                 //const __wchar_t __pin * stan_string = PtrToStringChars(file_name);
                ofstream outfile;
                outfile.open("Test.txt", ios::out | ios::app );
                outfile<<stan_string<<endl;
                outfile.close();

                int number_of_lines = 0;
                string line,tempLine;
                ifstream myfile("Test.txt");

                while (std::getline(myfile, line))
                    ++number_of_lines;
                    myfile.close();
                ifstream my_file("Test.txt");
                    for(int i=number_of_lines;i>0;i--)
                 {
                    std::getline(my_file,line);
                    history[i] = line;

                 }
                 my_file.close();
                 ofstream out_file;
                 string fn="history.txt";
                 out_file.open(fn.c_str());
                 for(int i=1;i<=number_of_lines;i++)
                 {
                    out_file<<history[i]<<endl;
                 }
                 out_file.close();

                 String^ ReadedFile=File::ReadAllText("history.txt");
                 label1->Text = ReadedFile;

                 ifstream inFile;
                 ofstream oFile;
                 inFile.open("history.txt");
                 oFile.open("names.txt");

                 while (getline (inFile,line) ){
                // cout << line << endl;
                 int pos = line.find_last_of("\\");

                if (string::npos != pos){
                    tempLine = line.erase(0, pos + 1);
                }

                oFile << tempLine << endl;

                }

                inFile.close();
                oFile.close();
                no_of_clicks++;
                ifstream in_file("names.txt");
                    for(int i=0;i<number_of_lines;i++)
                 {
                    std::getline(in_file,line);
                    record[i] = line;

                 }
                 in_file.close();

                if (no_of_clicks>5){
                    no_of_clicks=no_of_clicks-5;

                }
                   History_Links();
}
void MarshalString ( String ^ s, string& os ) {
     using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
     System::IntPtr pointer = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s);
      char* charPointer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pointer.ToPointer());
     std::string returnString(charPointer, s->Length);
     Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pointer);
     os = returnString;

    }

public: void History_Links()
{
                string name0=record[0];
                string name1=record[1];
                string name2=record[2];
                string name3=record[3];             
                string name4=record[4];
                this->linkLabel1->Text=gcnew String(name0.c_str());
                this->linkLabel2->Text=gcnew String(name1.c_str());
                this->linkLabel3->Text=gcnew String(name2.c_str());
                this->linkLabel4->Text=gcnew String(name3.c_str());
                this->linkLabel5->Text=gcnew String(name4.c_str());


}

int history_reader()
{
    int number_of_lines = 0;
            string line;
            ifstream myfile("Test.txt");

            while (std::getline(myfile, line))
                ++number_of_lines;
                myfile.close();
            ifstream my_file("Test.txt");
                for(int i=number_of_lines;i>0;i--)
             {
                std::getline(my_file,line);
                history[i] = line;
             }
                my_file.close();
                return number_of_lines;
}


private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 // Application::Exit();
}

private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            std::ofstream oftest;
            oftest.open("Test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
            oftest.close();
            std::ofstream ofhistory;
            ofhistory.open("history.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
            ofhistory.close();
            std::ofstream ofnames;
            ofnames.open("names.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
            ofnames.close();
            Application::Exit();
}
private: System::Void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e) {
            history_reader();    
            string str1=history[1];
            String^ str2 = gcnew String(str1.c_str());
            //axAcroPDF1->src=str2;
            OpenFileDialog^ opendialog =gcnew OpenFileDialog;
            opendialog->FileName=str2;
            //opendialog-> ShowDialog(); 
            axAcroPDF1->src=opendialog->FileName;
         }
private: System::Void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e) {
            history_reader();    
            string str1=history[2];
            String^ str2 = gcnew String(str1.c_str());
            //axAcroPDF1->src=str2;
            OpenFileDialog^ opendialog =gcnew OpenFileDialog;
            opendialog->FileName=str2;
            //opendialog-> ShowDialog(); 
            axAcroPDF1->src=opendialog->FileName;
         }
private: System::Void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e) {
            history_reader();    
            string str1=history[3];
            String^ str2 = gcnew String(str1.c_str());
            //axAcroPDF1->src=str2;
            OpenFileDialog^ opendialog =gcnew OpenFileDialog;
            opendialog->FileName=str2;
            //opendialog-> ShowDialog(); 
            axAcroPDF1->src=opendialog->FileName;
         }
private: System::Void linkLabel4_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e) {
            history_reader();    
            string str1=history[4];
            String^ str2 = gcnew String(str1.c_str());
            //axAcroPDF1->src=str2;
            OpenFileDialog^ opendialog =gcnew OpenFileDialog;
            opendialog->FileName=str2;
            //opendialog-> ShowDialog(); 
            axAcroPDF1->src=opendialog->FileName;
         }
private: System::Void linkLabel5_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e) {
            history_reader();    
            string str1=history[5];
            String^ str2 = gcnew String(str1.c_str());
            //axAcroPDF1->src=str2;
            OpenFileDialog^ opendialog =gcnew OpenFileDialog;
            opendialog->FileName=str2;
            //opendialog-> ShowDialog(); 
            axAcroPDF1->src=opendialog->FileName;
         }
};
}
```

Comment: I've Solved the problem, The creation of linklabel is not actually dynamic but it acts dynamic and is far easy than previous approach which took me days...